# JQuery specific problem - PHP JSON return

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a problem with processing a JSON object.

When I do `echo` the result I get this:

```
result : undefined
```

[image: Image of undefined result]

```
$.post("./php/date_information.php", function(temp){
        alert(temp.weekNumber); // HERE
        $('select[name="week"]').val(temp.weekNumber);
      });
```

but when I change my code I get this

```
result : {"year":"2018","weekNumber":"39","status":"200"}
```

[image: Image of correct]

```
$.post("./php/date_information.php", function(temp){
        alert(temp); // Here
        $('select[name="week"]').val(temp.weekNumber);
      });
```

PHP script return (JSON FORMAT):

```
{"year":"2018","weekNumber":"39","status":"200"}
```

I have no idea why JQuery doesn't take `temp.weekNumber`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the content type to json in your PHP script, before echoing the content

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```